# How to use binding in a TabItem with DataTemplate in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datatemplate, tabcontrol

I'm trying to do something basic (I think!), but I've got a problem. I have got a TabControl and 3 TabItems. The 2 first items must be untouched, and I want to apply a dataTemplate on the third tabItem, so I used a DataTemplateSelector. This is OK, it works. But then, I want to fill data in the third tabItem with my datamodel. Binding is not working because my DataContext is always "null" in the tabItem. How can I set the DataContext in the tabItem created by the dataTemplate ? Here is my code :

XAML :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="910" Width="1200">

<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="configurationTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:ConfigurationDatamodel}">
        <local:ConfigurationTemplateUC DataContext="{Binding DataContext.ConfigurationDatamodel}" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <local:TabItemTemplateSelector ConfigurationTemplate="{StaticResource configurationTemplate}" x:Key="tabItemTemplateSelector"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <TabControl Height="800" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="tabControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource tabItemTemplateSelector}">
        <TabItem Header="TabItem1" Name="tabItem1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <some stuff />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="TabItem2" Name="tabItem2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <some stuff />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="TabItem3" Name="tabItem3" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

UserControl of my DataTemplate :

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.ConfigurationTemplateUC"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="800" d:DesignWidth="1000">
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Label Content="File name : " Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="50,43,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="16"/>
    <Label Content="{Binding Path=File}" FontSize="16" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="160,43,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="324" />
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Datamodel :

```
public class ConfigurationDatamodel
{
    private string file;

    public string File
    {
        get { return this.file; }
        set 
        { 
            this.file= value;
        }
    }

    public ConfigurationDatamodel()
    {}

    public ConfigurationDatamodel(string file)
    {
        this.file= file;
    }
}
```

Code-behind :

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        ConfigurationDatamodel dt1 = new ConfigurationDatamodel("example.txt");
        InitializeComponent();

        tabItem3.DataContext = dt1;
    }
```

There is no binding errors in the console, but the label containing the filename is always empty. The DataContext of the UserControl "ConfigurationTemplateUC" is always "null".

Any thoughts?

**EDIT**

If I set the DataContext in the contructor of the UserControl, it works :

```
public ConfigurationTemplateUC()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ConfigurationDatamodel dt1 = new ConfigurationDatamodel("example.txt");
        this.DataContext = dt1;
    }
```

How can I set this dataContext with the DataTemplate ?

Comment: You shouldn't include "DataContext." in your binding path (bindings work directly on the `DataContext` object). Try `<Label Content="{Binding Path=File}" ...`

Comment: Still same problem, the DataContext is null. But I think you're right, I modify the question with your remark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `DataTemplate`, Remove the `DataContext` binding from

```
<local:ConfigurationTemplateUC DataContext="{Binding DataContext.ConfigurationDatamodel}" />
```

...leaving only

```
<local:ConfigurationTemplateUC />
```

UI in a `DataTemplate` automatically gets the bound data as its `DataContext`, so in your case you override the correct DataTemplate with a path to something that can't be found.

**EDIT:**

Also, you don't need a `DataTemplateSelector` to do this. You can remove the selector and instead simply use `TabItem.ContentTemplate`:

```
<TabItem Header="TabItem3" Name="tabItem3" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource configurationTemplate}" >
    ...
```

Comment: It's not working, the dataContext is still null :(  But thank you for the TabItem.ContentTemplate

Comment: Ah, of course: In `MainWindow`'s constructor, set `tabItem3.Content = dt1` (*not* `.DataContext`). It's a tab item's `Content` that is fed to `ContentTemplate`.